# How to add SQLite manage

Tags: windows, firefox, sqlite, addons

> I remove it by mistake from my Addons.
>
> Now i can't add and this message is displayed: "This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox.".
>
> What can i do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search Mozilla Firefox Add-ons?

You do not state Firefox version, but if it's Quantum (v. 57 or later, I believe), a quick search shows other, compatible, SQLite addons, such as [SeLite Connection Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selite-sqlite-connection-mg/).

Comment: Thenks, but i don't know how can i get again the Add-ons that i remove before.And i am new in this and i don't know how to use SeLite Connection Manager